# Why does a Rust project doing async network IO using Tokio have thousands of writes to file descriptor 5?

Tags: linux, rust, system-calls, rust-tokio

I am profiling my code for system calls using `strace`. I found some surprising results. The trace shows 47254 single byte writes to file descriptor 5 while doing a network transfer of 200Mb data.

```
write(5, "\1", 1)
```

What does this write mean? What is fd 5? Where could it be originating from? Is there a way to find out?

I am not very well versed with Linux fundamentals.

Output of `ls -lrt /proc/24393/fd`

```
lrwx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 9 -> 'socket:[97676]'
lr-x------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 7 -> /dev/random
lr-x------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 6 -> /dev/urandom
l-wx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 5 -> 'pipe:[98345]'
lr-x------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 4 -> 'pipe:[98345]'
lrwx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 3 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 95th 95th 64 Mar  1 20:56 0 -> /dev/pts/0
```

I checked what that pipe is (though that didn't help much):

```
/proc/24393/fd$ lsof | grep 98345
btrs      24393       95th    4r     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
btrs      24393       95th    5w     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
tokio-run 24393 24394 95th    4r     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
tokio-run 24393 24394 95th    5w     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
tokio-run 24393 24395 95th    4r     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
tokio-run 24393 24395 95th    5w     FIFO               0,11       0t0            98345 pipe
```

Comment: Check in /proc/$PID/fd what you see.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385569/is-it-possible-to-write-to-other-file-descriptors-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: 5 is a file descriptor... why should it be special ?? do you know what is a file descriptor ? Guess it's the socket where the program write 200 Mo...

Comment: @Jay-Pi Thanks. I found that it's a pipe. Updated the question. Not sure how/why its created.

Comment: @Stargateur - I didn't know that. As I said, I don't have a lot of linux experience. I updated the question, if that helps. I am using `BufStream` around the `TcpStream` (1Mb buffer) to help reduce syscalls.

Comment: @Stargateur - Also, I see that my requests are written using `sendto` and response is received using `recvfrom` syscalls. This seems to be something else.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes, a pipe can between processes or sockets or all kind of stuff.

Comment: @Jay-Pi Is there a way to find out more about what this pipe connecting? what is being transferred in it?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Was answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/221955/monitor-interprocess-pipe-traffic).

Comment: @Jay-Pi: I just tried that. I am seeing the same thing I saw with direct strace: `write(5, "\1", 1)                       = 1` :D

Comment: @GurwinderSingh With both straces ? But you did restart the program/software?

Comment: @jay-Pi yes, it is using that same one between runs. (I am on WSL(2) if that matters)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939394/extra-1-character-in-printf). In ASCI \1 should be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-of-Header#Basic_ASCII_control_codes). Sorry, I cant help you more. I guess this character is send to indicate that something may follow later.

Comment: Probably used for tokio internal signalling, possibly from [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio/src/signal/unix.rs#L214).

Comment: @Hasturkun - That seems to be it. If I change the number of tokio threads to 1 using `#[tokio::main(core_threads = 1, max_threads = 1)]`, these writes go away. I'll open bug in tokio repo as these writes have non-trivial cost. Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These writes are used by mio (as part of the tokio implementation) to wake up worker threads that are in a epoll_wait syscall, when they are awoken by something other than a file descriptor trigger. Since the threads are blocked in the OS on a syscall, this requires a syscall of some sort to tell the OS to unblock them. This could be caused by a channel. If you are seeing this, then that would suggest you have workers that are idle. The alternatives to using this syscall are to keep those threads in a polling busywait (much more expensive in syscalls and CPU time), or to just not use the workers at all until they are woken by external I/O (limiting your concurrency). I would suggest you look at whether these are actually  performance impact or caused by bottlenecks elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/2287) with tokio. If I change the `core_threads` to 1 or use `basic_scheduler`, those writes go away. Also, these writes seem to have effect on CPU efficiency and download speed.